# Cantor doesn't recognize the Sage backend

Tags: sagemath

I installed the package `cantor-backend-sage`, and then started up cantor, but Sage isn't one of the options for the backend when it starts up. How can I get cantor to use sage as a backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, also you should install Sage. And after that you should select menu Settings --> Configure, then the 'Sage' tab and enter the path to sage.